# PHP preg_grep reverse matching pattern

Tags: php, regex

I built a simple code which parses all music folders inside several disks and put the list into an array.

The folders names begin with multiple spaces when they are categories, with a single space when they are "final folders". E.g. see this structure:

```
[0] => /Volumes/SAMPLES/  VOCALS/
[1] => /Volumes/SAMPLES/  VOCALS/  AFRICA/
[2] => /Volumes/SAMPLES/  VOCALS/ AcmeInc Club Vocals/
[3] => /Volumes/SAMPLES/  VOCALS/ AtomicInc Dance Vocals/
[4] => /Volumes/SAMPLES/  VOCALS/  AFRICA/ AfroInc Zulu Vocals/
[5] => /Volumes/SAMPLES/  VOCALS/  AFRICA/ SampleInc Warriors/
[6] => /Volumes/SAMPLES/  VOCALS/  AFRICA/ SampleInc Warriors/SampleInc_Warriors_Ululation/
[7] => /Volumes/SAMPLES/  VOCALS/  AFRICA/ SampleInc Warriors/SampleInc_Warriors_Drums/
```

and so on... I need to select the final folders only and tried several combinations of greedy and non greedy patterns, starting from the final $
E.g. the following path doesn't work:

```
$pattern = "#\/ ([:alnum:]+?)/$#i";
$matches  = preg_grep ($pattern, $root);
```

The expected result should have been:

```
[3] => /Volumes/SAMPLES/  VOCALS/ AcmeInc Club Vocals/
[4] => /Volumes/SAMPLES/  VOCALS/ AtomicInc Dance Vocals/
[5] => /Volumes/SAMPLES/  VOCALS/  AFRICA/ AfroInc Zulu Vocals/
[6] => /Volumes/SAMPLES/  VOCALS/  AFRICA/ SampleInc Warriors/
```

Instead I get all the folders or none or orphans. Please consider that special chars like &or ! could be in the folder name. Thank you for the suggestions, 3 days,tried everything, desperate, thanks!

Comment: I think you can try `'~/ \w+(?: +\w+)*/$~'` regex. Or if you can have any non-word characters there, use `'~/ [^/\s]+(?: +[^/\s]+)*/$~'`.

Comment: Why not use http://php.net/manual/en/ref.dir.php instead of regex?

Comment: @dognose: Please, could you write an answer using these functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working regex:

```
'~/(?:  +[^/\s]+)*/ [^/\s]+(?: +[^/\s]+)*/$~'
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wG8vE7/3)

It matches:

- `/(?:  +[^/\s]+)*` - a non-final subfolder (`/`, then more than 1 spaces, 1 or more characters other than space or `/`)
- `/` - a forward slash with a space after it
- `[^/\s]+` - 1 or more characters other than a whitespace or forward slash
- `(?: +[^/\s]+)*` - 0 or more sequences of ...

  - `+` - 1 or more regular spaces
  - `[^/\s]+` - 1 or more characters other than a whitespace or forward slash
- `/` - a forward slash
- `$` - end of string

See [PHP code demo](http://ideone.com/c5CHMn):

```
$ar = array("/Volumes/SAMPLES/  VOCALS/", 
    "/Volumes/SAMPLES/  VOCALS/  AFRICA/",
    "/Volumes/SAMPLES/  VOCALS/ AcmeInc Club Vocals/",
    "/Volumes/SAMPLES/  VOCALS/ AtomicInc Dance Vocals/",
    "/Volumes/SAMPLES/  VOCALS/  AFRICA/ AfroInc Zulu Vocals/",
    "/Volumes/SAMPLES/  VOCALS/  AFRICA/ SampleInc Warriors/",
    "/Volumes/SAMPLES/  VOCALS/  AFRICA/ SampleInc Warriors/SampleInc_Warriors_Ululation/",
    "/Volumes/SAMPLES/  VOCALS/  AFRICA/ SampleInc Warriors/SampleInc_Warriors_Drums/",
    "/Volumes/SAMPLES/  VOCALS/  AFRICA/ AfroInc Zulu Vocals/ Folder1/"
    );
$n = preg_grep('~/(?:  +[^/\s]+)*/ [^/\s]+(?: +[^/\s]+)*/$~', $ar);
print_r($n);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [2] => /Volumes/SAMPLES/  VOCALS/ AcmeInc Club Vocals/
    [3] => /Volumes/SAMPLES/  VOCALS/ AtomicInc Dance Vocals/
    [4] => /Volumes/SAMPLES/  VOCALS/  AFRICA/ AfroInc Zulu Vocals/
    [5] => /Volumes/SAMPLES/  VOCALS/  AFRICA/ SampleInc Warriors/
)
```

Comment: almost done! It still gets folders like e.g. /Volumes/SAMPLES/  VOCALS/  AFRICA/ AfroInc Zulu Vocals/ Folder1/

Comment: @fab: Isn't `"/Volumes/SAMPLES/  VOCALS/  AFRICA/ AfroInc Zulu Vocals/ Folder1/"` a folder that must be extracted? If not, why?

Comment: It should be the first occurrence since it's a subfolder of the "final folder", sorry to bother you, I wasn't really clear.

Comment: As you can see [here, with `preg_grep('~/\h{2,}[^/]+/\h[^/\s]+(?:\h+[^/\s]+)*/$~', $ar);`](http://ideone.com/w4onxP) it works in the code demo.

Comment: worked adding the case insensitive modifier, here's the complete working version! Thanks stribizhev!

 $pattern = "/\/(?:  +[^\/\s]+)*\/ [^\/\s]+(?: +[^\/\s]+)*\/$/i";

Comment: The `/i` modifier does not do anything in this regex since there are no letters in it. If you have Unicode letters in your strings, you just need to add `/u` modifier.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to ensure that the next character after the space is not a space too.

```
$result = preg_grep('~/ [^/ ][^/]*/\z~', $root);
```

pattern details:

```
/          # literal slash
[ ]        # literal space
[^/ ]      # a character except a slash or a space
[^/]*      # zero or more characters that are not a slash
/          # literal slash
\z         # end of the string
```

[demo](https://eval.in/455656)